# Multiple transition properties not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've had this CSS for some time, and suddenly I noticed it's not working in new versions of Firfox.

```
-moz-transition: all .3s, top 0s, left 0s;
```

So the original idea was opacity & scaling transforms would animate while top and left would not animate.  I know using "opacity .3s" will work, but I need my scale transform to work also.  I'm also aware of the CSS "zoom" property, but that will not work for my needs.

Basically, I just want this to work and I have no idea why this correct CSS is suddenly broken in Firefox.  If anyone has an alternative solution, that would be great.

Comment: Test case? http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what version the issue started, but the last two releases of Firefox are afflicted. http://jsfiddle.net/9J5vc/

Comment: SO in what I uploaded, you'll see the scale transition does not work in Firefox, but if you change it to "-moz-transition: all .3s" it works.  The problem is I can't have positioning animating.

Answer (score 1):

Ssssup doode,
instead of `all` put `transform`. Like this:

```
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s, top 0s, left 0s;
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/9J5vc/3/

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem with the lastest versions of Firefox and not your code. I have half a dozen sites that are not properly rendering css in firefox at this time. they were all fine not more than a week ago and no change to the code or codebase was made. the styles still work in other browsers.

Firefox is having issues on thier current release of the browser and I am sure they are all aware of it, but really, if it does not get fixed soon, they will loose even more market share. which would be a shame really.

Comment: Apart from here, is there a logged bug or so with mozilla?

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=835007 (similar question: [14533519](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533519) and was recently fixed for the Firefox 21 milestone. Until then, you can't use `all` as part of multiple transitions and have to specify every property separately.

To be fair though, only the [most recent W3C draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20130212/#transition-property-property) explicitly states this behaviour; [earlier versions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transitions-20120403/#transition-property-property) were not very clear how this case should be handled.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me..

```
-moz-transition: bottom .3s, right .3s, top 0s, left 0s;
```

Also make sure your element is still positioned.

Comment: I'm using "-moz-transform: scale" and I need that to animate as it would if I had been using "-moz-transition: all .3s".  The only catch is I need positioning itself not to animate.  This CSS once worked, but no longer in recent versions of Firefox.