# How can I specify a CSS3 transition to all properties, but with one exception/override?

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions

I have a CSS transition set up on an element, with all properties being affected. I don't know ahead of time which CSS properties will change, so I have no choice but to use "all" despite the [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947441/css3-transitions-is-transition-all-slower-than-transition-x).

```
.a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

However, I want a specific property to have its own transition settings different from every other property:

```
.a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out, margin-top 5s linear;
}
```

According to the [W3C grammar for transition-property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property-property), other values should be allowed after 'all' is specified.

However, this doesn't seem to work in Firefox (18) and Opera (12). It works correctly in Chrome/Safari (with prefix) and IE10.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/F7tb5/3/

Is there a way to get this to work in all modern browsers without manually enumerating all properties that could possibly change?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it looks like the issue here is that the spec changed after some initial implementations...  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=835007

Comment: Thanks Boris! It does appear to be a bug.

Comment: Well, as the spec is written now it is.  As it was written several months ago it's not...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=835007 (similar question: [14533519](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533519) but was recently fixed for the Firefox 21 milestone. Until then, you can't use `all` as part of multiple transitions and have to specify every property separately.

To be fair though, only the [most recent W3C draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20130212/#transition-property-property) explicitly states this behaviour; [earlier versions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transitions-20120403/#transition-property-property) were not very clear how this case should be handled.

I had a similar case and the work-around was to create a wrapper element that animates all properties that are known before and leave `all` for the actual elements:

```
.wrap.a {
  transition: margin-top 5s linear;
}

.wrap.a .inner {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```